# How do you access HttpContext in the constructor of a Controller in .NET Core 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

How do you access HttpContext in the constructor of a Controller in .NET Core 3.1?

It always seems to be null in the constructor, but is available in the actual methods. This was possible in MVC 4 and this has come up while trying to port the project to .NET Core.

If I try and use the HttpContextAccessor through DI, this fails with an exception:

`InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContextAccessor' while attempting to activate 'MyProject.Controllers.UsersController'`

Comment: Are you injecting the interface and not the concrete type?

Comment: I don't think you can do that in .NET Core, and I would question why you are doing that in the first place.

Comment: Short Answer: **You cant**.

Comment: You will only have access to the HttpContext after the controller has been initialized and is handling a request.

Comment: @DavidG - it's just a singleton in the DI container; you should be able to inject it anywhere.  Whether it's wise/useful to in this scenario is a different matter...

Comment: @Nkosi - I just did it; works fine.  Same caveat as on the previous comment.

Comment: @DavidG The issue is that I need to initialise some services with a value which comes from the user. In MVC 4 I did this in the constructor so it was in a single place. Now it seems I need to do it in each of the ~15 functions on the controller which seems messy.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `IHttpContextAccessor` for access to `HttpContext`.

for access `HttpContext` you must add `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()` to `ConfigureService` method

```cs
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

and get `IHttpContextAccessor` from Dependency Injection in constructor

```cs
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public UsersController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

access to `HttpContext`

```cs
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this has upvotes.  As I said in my question, I've tried that already and it doesn't work in the *constructor* of a controller - it just throws an exception.

Comment: @NickG But I use it according to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components) and there is no problem.

Comment: The documentation doesn't show it being actively used in the controller. Only assigned to a local variable. If you use it to try and get to HttpContext.Request for example, you get the exception I posted.

Comment: Worked well using Core 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this with filters. Not within your constructor. This is not thread safe: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0